# Windows 8.1 remember two users at start-up

Tags: windows-8, login-screen

I have a computer running Windows 8.1 which I use for some work ( logging in to ActiveDirectory ) and at home ( just using a local user profile ) and although this works fine, it seems a bit laborious when I start up the machine to constantly have to go to "change user" then manually type in the details. Is there any way to tell Windows to remember two ( or more ) login profiles rather than just the last one used?

Comment: No; Are you logging out of the user profile before you ahutdown?

Comment: @Ramhound I am just shutting down directly, no manual log-out.

Comment: Try my suggestion.  By doing so when you start your computer you select which user you want to log into.